# Invoking conversion operators

Tags: c++, operators

What's the reason for the following behavior?

```
class BoolWrapper
{
public:
    BoolWrapper(bool value) : value(value) {}

    operator bool() const { return value; }
    operator int() const { return (int) value; }

private:
    bool value;
};


BoolWrapper bw(true);

if (bw) { ... }            // invokes operator bool()
if (bw == true) { ... }    // invokes operator int() -- why?
```

Is this behavior expected? (Using GCC 4.7.2.)

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say "integral promotions" in the context of the built-in `==`...

Comment: Because of this you should define explicitly `bool operator==(bool);`

Comment: @ahenderson That would be illegal. User-defined operators must take at least one parameter of a user-defined type.

Comment: @Gorpik That does not sound right. I'm referring to the operator as a member function. Are you referring to the operator as a global function? Here is a [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) that shows the outside and inside class definitions.

Comment: @ahenderson Sorry, I did not notice that your `operator==` received a single parameter and was thus a member function. In this case you are right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your expectations are based on your belief that the language already knows how to compare two `bool` values. In reality it doesn't, however surprising it might sound. More precisely, the language "does not know" how to do it *directly*.

At the conceptual level, C++ does not have a dedicated built-in equality comparison operator for `bool vs. bool` comparisons. Even when you write `true == false` in your code, it is really interpreted by the language as `(int) true == (int) false`. The implicit conversion to `int` is introduced by the rules of *usual arithmetic conversions* and `int vs. int` comparison is used afterwards.

The most immediate built-in operator that can compare two `bool` values is the one for `int vs. int` comparison. This is the operator the compiler is trying to use in your case as well. The very same operator will be used for `char vs. char` and `short vs. short` comparisons.

In other words, the only way the compiler can use your `bool` conversion operator in the `bw == true` expression would be to do

```
(int)(bool) bw == (int) true
```

This is certainly less "optimal" than the direct

```
(int) bw == (int) true
```

This is the logic that drives the language to select the latter variant.

Comment: I don't see how a conforming compiler can promote `short` to `unsigned int`. As for `char`, only if it is unsigned and the size of `int` is one byte (exotic indeed).

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about `unsigned` versions of these types. I removed the misleading remark about exotic platforms.

Comment: The *compiler* might not know how to compare anything other than `int`, but the *optimizer* often does. It's useful to know the difference.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: This is exactly the meaning I try to convey when I say "interpreted by the language". "By the language" is intended to be synonymous with "conceptually", "by abstract C++ machine". Of course, in the generated physical machine code the conversion to `int` is completely unnecessary. And I wouldn't even call it "optimization".

Comment: +1 from me then. In this specific case, the compiler must select the `int` user defined conversion to avoid being non-conformant, regardless of optimisations or anything.

Comment: I only bring it up because if someone were to show the compiled assembly for `a_bool == b_bool` they might get confused. Your answer makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 6):

From 5/9:

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or
>   enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar
>   way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of
>   the result. This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions,
>   which are defined as follows:

[Some floating point items that don't matter.]

> Otherwise, the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on both
>   operands.

And from 3.9.1/6 we see that bool is eligible for integral promotion:

> Values of type bool are either true or false.42) [Note: there are no
>   signed, unsigned, short, or long bool types or values. ] As described
>   below, bool values behave as integral types. Values of type bool
>   participate in integral promotions (4.5).

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Accepted Andrey's answer, though, for his `(int)(bool) bw == (int) true` example.

Answer (score 4):

In the first case, an `if` clause expects a `bool` condition, so this is the selected conversion.

In the second case, you are asking for a comparison between a `BoolWrapper` and a `bool`. Since no `operator ==` overload exists to do it, the compiler must convert these arguments into suitable ones. According to the standard (section 4.5, *Integral promotions*), the preferred integral type for conversions is `int`. Since both `BoolWrapper` and `bool` can be converted to `int`, this is the selected conversion.

Comment: I don't follow this logic entirely. So what if `BoolWrapper` and `bool`can be converted to int? `BoolWrapper` and `bool` can be converted to (or stay) `bool` too. Why is the integer conversion (which requires both sides to convert) chosen over the bool conversion which requires only one side to convert?

Comment: @Dave See my answer, the standard mandates that integral promotions will happen for both arguments for `==`.

Comment: @Dave: It may be argued that it makes more sense to do just one conversion (`BoolWrapper` to `bool`, in this case) rather than two. But the standard has the final word on that and it mandates to convert both values to `int` if it can.

Comment: @Dave, the standard doesn't differentiate the cases where a `bool` conversion makes sense such as `==` and a case where it doesn't such as `+`. If you're applying any arithmetic operator it will choose `int`.